# Unable to set field/property CartItems on entity type BusinessEntitys.Product

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, wcf, ado.net

I spent many hours (including wide Google search) trying to figure out what the problem is. Unfortunately, without success.
The error that I get is: "Unable to set field/property CartItems on entity type BusinessEntitys.Product. See InnerException for details."
the **innerExeption** is **null**.
The error occurs at addToCart() function when I try to call a function **addCartItem** through the WCF. When the call get to DAL and try to save the new object in db context it's failed.

```
public void AddToCart(int id)
{
    // Retrieve the product from the database.           
    ShoppingCartId = GetCartId();

    CartItem cartItem = new BLFrontend().getAllCartItems().SingleOrDefault(
         c => c.CartItemId == ShoppingCartId
         && c.ProductId == id);
    if (cartItem == null)
    {
        Product temp = new BLFrontend().getAllProducts().SingleOrDefault(
             p => p.ProductId == id);
        // Create a new cart item if no cart item exists.                 
        cartItem = new CartItem
        {
            CartItemId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            ProductId = id,
            CartId_ = ShoppingCartId,
            Product = temp,
            Quantity = 1,
        };

        new BLFrontend().addCartItem(cartItem);//The problem starts from here
    }
    else
    {
        cartItem.Quantity++;
        //update
    }
```

I'm using EF in my project, this is the Model:

```
namespace BusinessEntitys
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class CartItem
{
    public string CartItemId { get; set; }
    public string CartId_ { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
}
```

class Product that contained in CratItem:

```
    namespace BusinessEntitys
    {
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq; // added this

    public partial class Product
    {
        public Product()
        {
            this.ItemInOrders = new HashSet<ItemInOrder>();
            this.CartItems = new HashSet<CartItem>();
        }

        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public double ProductBasePrice { get; set; }
        public double ProductDiscount { get; set; }
        public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
        public string ProductImageURL { get; set; }
        public string ProductQualityLevel { get; set; }
        public string ProductCategory { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CartItem> CartItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My BusinessEntitys is:

```
namespace BusinessEntitys
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class StoreDBEntities : DbContext
    {
        public StoreDBEntities()
            : base("name=StoreDBEntities")
        {
            base.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<ItemInOrder> ItemInOrders { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<StockManagment> StockManagments { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<CartItem> CartItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Execption occurs here in my DAL at 2nd line when trying to execute the command:
**context.CartItems.Add(CartItemToAdd)**

```
 public bool addCartItem(CartItem CartItemToAdd)
        {
            try
            {
                var context = new StoreDBEntities();
                context.CartItems.Add(CartItemToAdd);
                return context.SaveChanges() > 0;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

The stackTracer:

> StackTrace    "at DataAccess.Dal.addCartItem(CartItem CartItemToAdd) in
>   c:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\OrGarden\DataAccess\Dal.cs:line 406\r\n   at
>   BusinessLogicBackend.BLBackend.addCartItem(CartItem cartItemToAdd) in
>   c:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\OrGarden\BusinessLogicBackend\BLBackend.cs:line
>   293\r\n   at SyncInvokeaddCartItem(Object , Object[] , Object[] )\r\n 
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)\r\n   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)" string

Important Update: When i deleted this assignment `Product = temp,` the **addCartItem** call succeed saved without a problem. Only that the field **Product** remains **null**.
The code after that change:

```
Product temp =  business.getAllProducts().SingleOrDefault(
                     p => p.ProductId == id);
                // Create a new cart item if no cart item exists.                 
                cartItem = new CartItem
                {
                    CartItemId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    ProductId = id,
                    CartId_ = ShoppingCartId,
                    Product = temp,
                    Quantity = 1,
                };

                 business.addCartItem(cartItem);
```

Whene i retrieved CrartItem from the context the field **Product** remains **null**.

Can anyone help me fix that bad problem??

Thank you very much,
Ron

Comment: one first problem is, imho, you are mixing 2 contexts: probably one in `BLFrontend().getAllProducts()` the other in `BLFrontend().addCartItem(cartItem)`.

Comment: The error seems like `context` does not have a CartItems Property. (Also your code seems to confirm this, though I can't see the class `DbContext`). If you use `StoreDBEntities context` instead of `var context`, intellisense should point this out to you.

Comment: @tschmit007 What I have to change if two contexts make the error? In Dal the code of getAllProducts() is: `public List<Product> getAllProducts()
        {
            try
            {
                List<Product> ls = new StoreDBEntities().Products.ToList();
                return ls;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }`

Comment: @HW You can see above in BusinessEntitys that there is CartItems property. Also i tried your suggestion, unfortunately it didn't fix my problem. Thanks!

Comment: the context instanciation should not be part of the method, but (for example) of a constructor of the class

Comment: On your `context.SaveChanges()` look for a `DbUpdateException` for more details on whats going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I strongly recommend you take a look at the [Unit of Work pattern](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) ([MSDN version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx), if you prefer).

The problem is, you're creating a new instance of `BLFrontEnd` and `StoreDBEntities` every time. It seems that there's no reason to create the instances so.

I'm not sure what exactly going on inside the BLFrontEnd, but I bet every methods on the BLFrontEnd also create a new StoreDBEntities instance. And that might be the cause of the exception.

You need to manage the life cycle of instances. look at this:

```
public void AddToCart(int id)
{
    // Begins new life-cycle of BLFrontend
    var frontend = new BLFrontend();
    // or you can wrap it using statement.
    // using(var frontend = new BLFrontend())
    // {
    //    ... code ...
    // }

    // Retrieve the product from the database.           
    ShoppingCartId = GetCartId();

    CartItem cartItem = frontend.getAllCartItems().SingleOrDefault(
         c => c.CartItemId == ShoppingCartId
         && c.ProductId == id);
    if (cartItem == null)
    {
        Product temp = frontend.getAllProducts().SingleOrDefault(
             p => p.ProductId == id);
        // Create a new cart item if no cart item exists.                 
        cartItem = new CartItem
        {
            CartItemId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            ProductId = id,
            CartId_ = ShoppingCartId,
            Product = temp,
            Quantity = 1,
        };

        frontend.addCartItem(cartItem);//The problem starts from here
    }
    else
    {
        cartItem.Quantity++;
        //update
    }

    // end of life-cycle of the instance.
    frontend.Dispose();
}


public class BLFrontEnd : IDispose
{
    private readonly StoreDBEntities dbContext;
    public BLFrontEnd()
    {
        dbContext = new StoreDBEntities();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        dbContext.Dispose();
    }

    public IQueryable<Cart> getAllCartItems()
    {
       // your logics...
       return dbContext.Carts.AsQueryable();
    }

    public IQueryable<Product> getAllProducts()
    {
       // your logics...
       return dbContext.Products.AsQueryable();
    }

    public bool addCartItem(CartItem CartItemToAdd)
        {
            try
            {
                //var context = new StoreDBEntities();
                dbContext.CartItems.Add(CartItemToAdd);
                return context.SaveChanges() > 0;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
}
```

As you can see, 'A work' is beginning at the head of `AddToCart()` method, and ended at the tail of the method. That is the life-cycle of 'A work'. During the life-cycle, every resources are in the same context. That means every code in the life-cycle will use same instance of resources. It avoids unnecessary creation of new instance.

This code isn't that good, and you need to refactor in order to meet your use-cases and the architecture. But I hope you got the point.

**Edited**

Okay, to separate actual problem with your BL, could you try this:

```
public void AddToCart(int id)
{
    // use StoreDBEntities directly, instead of BLFrontend.
    using(var dbContext = new StoreDBEntities())
    {
        // Retrieve the product from the database.           
        ShoppingCartId = 123; // use magic number for this test.

        // and use dbContext directly.
        CartItem cartItem = dbContext.Carts.SingleOrDefault(
             c => c.CartItemId == ShoppingCartId
             && c.ProductId == id);
        if (cartItem == null)
        {
            Product temp = dbContext.Products.SingleOrDefault(
                 p => p.ProductId == id);
            // Create a new cart item if no cart item exists.                 
            cartItem = new CartItem
            {
                CartItemId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                ProductId = id,
                CartId_ = ShoppingCartId,
                Product = temp,
                Quantity = 1,
            };

            dbContext.Carts.Add(cartItem);
        }
        else
        {
            cartItem.Quantity++;
            //update
        }

        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Gongado Gong Thank you very much for the reply. I went through the code and changed it according to your explanation. Unfortunately it does not solve the problem.  Another suggestion maby?

Comment: @Roni Basically, the exception is that you're mixing 2 DbContext instaces at the same time, as tschmit007 said. I edited my answer. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: @GongadoGong Thanks for your update!!! I tried to change as you suggested to test, Luckily it's working good. Now, what i have to do for working through the Frontend - that mean working through the WCF. Our requirements are to do that through the WCF Service that represented by the Frontend. How to manage its instantiation's life cycle? Thanks!!!

Comment: @Roni I'm happy to here that! There're so many ways to manage object life-cycle. It will be a long story. Well, there's no simple answer that exactly suit for you. But essentially there're some design patterns and principals that related with those situation such as UoW(Unit of Work), IoC(Inversion of Control), DI(Dependency Injection), and so on. If you run out of time, just simplify your Frontend code like above. Then take a time to learn about those patterns and adopt it into your code. Hope it helps you.